# Using Vbscript, i'm fetching a value from textbox from UI. How to save that value to an xml tag

Tags: xml, vbscript

Below is the code that I tried to save SALEBLOCKENDDT tag in an xml file, which i'm fetching from UI textbox. When I run this I've "Object Variable not set" error.

Need a solution to save this tag value

```
    Dim nsPos
    Dim nsParms
    Dim szEndDate
    Dim sResult
    Dim sEndDate

    sEndDate   = Trim(GetFieldInput("cTxtEndDate"))
    Set nsPos = CreateObject("eSpace.esNamespace")
    Set nsParms = nsPOS.ApplyXML("POS\POS.xpa", 2)
    szEndDate = Trim(nsParms.PARAMETERS.SALEBLOCKENDDT.Text)

    If szEndDate = "" Then
        nsParms.PARAMETERS.SALEBLOCKENDDT.Text = sEndDate
    End If
    sResult = nsPOS.save("POS\POS.xpa",2)
```